# Noetherian PI rings are fully bounded

Tags: ring-theory

Can any one give me a precise reference for justifying that Noetherian PI rings are fully bounded. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a full proof [in this article by a pupil of Hajarnavis](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~gbellamy/ring.pdf) (see Proposition 5.3). In case the link dies, here's an improvised citation:

> Bellamy, Gwyn. *Localization in P.I. rings* (Supervised by C.R. Hajarnavis) (2006).

I haven't proofread the whole thing, but it seems OK.